# Mysql Logic for Many join tables records

Tags: mysql

I have written the following join query of 2 tables `ClientBillingRates` and `PayScaleLoaclJObCodes` which shows the price and current rate which is fine

```
SELECT ClientBillingRates.Price, PayScaleLoaclJObCodes.CurrentRate 
FROM ClientBillingRates 
JOIN PayScaleLoaclJObCodes 
ON ClientBillingRates.ClientBillingRates_ID=PayScaleLoaclJObCodes.JobCodeID
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is join the third table `WorkOrderLineItems`

Where

```
PayScalesLocal_ID.JobCodeID = WorkOrderLineItems.LineItems_LineItemID 
AND ClientBillingRates.ClientBillingRates_ID = WorkOrderLineItems.LineItems_LineItemID
```

I am not sure how to join the 3 tables as the logic is

1. Pull ALL `LineItems_LineItemID` from  `WorkOrderLineItems` Table
2. Then check in `PayScaleLoaclJObCodes.JobCodeID` table if `WorkOrderLineItems.LineItems_LineItemID` exists
3. Then check in `ClientBillingRates.JobCodeID` if `WorkOrderLineItems.LineItems_LineItemID` exists

Comment: What columns do you need to select? What to do if both or neither of the rows match with in step 2 and 3?

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema for each table, and which columns relate to each table.

Comment: @clinomaniac your solution worked with some edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT W.LineItems_LineItemID, C.Price, P.CurrentRate
FROM WorkOrderLineItems W
LEFT OUTER JOIN PayScaleLoaclJObCodes P
    ON W.LineItems_LineItemID = P.JobCodeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientBillingRates C
    ON W.LineItems_LineItemID = C.JobCodeID
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you need. Will update based on comments if required.